# WebStorm CSS cannot resolve custom property

Tags: css, webstorm, custom-properties

In my CSS file I'm using custom CSS as can be seen from the photo. WebStorm gives errors. How can I fix it?

When hovered on it full error is here

```
Cannot resolve '--color-gray-1' custom property
This inspection warns about CSS custom property variable references which cannot be resolved to any valid target
```

[image]

Comment: works fine for me using similar syntax. Please try invalidating caches (*File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart*). If it doesn't help, please create a support ticket, providing your `.css` file

Comment: Seems like it happens only on non-project files. There is a [youtrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53346) filed for it (unless it was you)

Answer (score 4):

Adding the property to custom CSS properties suppresses the 'Unknown CSS property' inspection; 
But in your screenshot I am guessing the warning comes from W3C validator. 
W3C Validator Inspection is based on external tool provided by W3C (online version available at http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input), so we can do nothing to fix such warnings.  Plus w3C validator is not always up-to-date and reports errors for valid CSS, but some users still like to have it enabled.

**You can only disable this inspection if you don't like these errors being displayed: hit Alt+Enter and choose 'Disable W3C CSS validation'.**

Comment: This is not the case, my phpstorm was working fine until few days ago (not showing error as soon as I add them). No updates were downloaded or installed ( I have been offline for past few weeks) which means there should be some settings accidentally triggered or files corrupted, causing this to appear.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure directory css file resides in is not excluded: right click on directory > Mark Directory As > Not Excluded

Comment: Explanation: That's a common problem when Libraries are marked as ignored for indexing. For example one would set the "node_modules" directory to ignored/excluded in general. Then you should Mark explicitly the Libraries where these stylings are defined as "Not excluded". (bootstrap, tailwind, material UI, etc. ...)

Answer (score 1):

two ways you can try：

```
1. :root {
     --color-gray-1: #666666;
   }

2. html, body {
     --color-gray-1: #666666;
     color: var(--color-gray-1)
   }
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?

Comment: As you can see, he already did that, just a few lines above!